# How to use 2 datasets in a single SSRS matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS 2012 to design a matrix report.

Matrix should retrieve data from 2 datasets in single column group

For Example:

`Dataset1`

```
Date            A   B

01-01-19        10  20
```

`Dataset2`

```
Date            A   C

01-01-19    5   30
```

`ExpectedResult`

```
Date            A   B   C

01-01-19        15  20  30
```

Columns might dynamically add up, hence we are using matrix.

Note: Cannot combine data from both the datasets at the database level as the datasets refer to 2 different datasources.

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use subreport, ssrs has provided  cool way of handling this.
does this help??
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5649/multidetail-reports-using-sub-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subreport. You need to use a Lookup in a regular table. Your 2 datasets need to have the same data format but with different column names (use alias's):

[image]

Create a new table with DataSet1 as the datasource and add the date field into the first column then put in the following formula into the other fields you wish to sum:

=Fields!ds1_col1.Value+Lookup(Fields!ds1_date.Value,Fields!ds2_date.Value,Fields!ds2_col1.Value,"DataSet2")

The formula is getting the DataSet1 field and using a Lookup to retrieve the corresponding DataSet2 value:

[image]

Results:
[image]

I hope this helps.

Rob

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. The solution you have provided holds good for Table. In my case I am using a matrix, so the columns are not fixed. Is there any solution for matrix?